# How to get the element in the array in mongoose/mongodb except the element we passed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is the structure of a document of the collection `Conversations`.
It contains participants array in an object which is inside messages array. Messages array contains several message objects like this :

```
{
  "_id": "5540b34347fdd4e917b80aa4",
  "messages": [{
    "from": "5530af38576214dd3553331c",
    "_id": "5540d5dc22f922061f68a41d",
    "participants": ["5530af38576214dd3553331c", "553f280040d50ef20f8c9d66"]
  }]
}
```

Here I am having the `messages.from` data and I want to get the element from the `messages.participants` array except `messages.from` element.

In the above example  `from` is `5530af38576214dd3553331c`.So I have to get the element `553f280040d50ef20f8c9d66` from the `messages.participants` array.

There are several documents like the above and for each document we have to do the same.

How can I do that in moongoose / mongodb ?

Comment: Please improve the format of the question. You will get good and quick replies from community if your question is genuine and understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach you could do is use [**lodash**](https://lodash.com/) library and in particular you'd want the [**difference**](https://lodash.com/docs#difference) method. This creates an array excluding all values of the provided arrays using `SameValueZero` for equality comparisons. Note: `SameValueZero` comparisons are like strict equality comparisons, e.g. `===`, except that `NaN` matches `NaN`.

So you could try the following:

```
Conservations.where("_id": "5540b34347fdd4e917b80aa4")
    .select({"messages": { "$elemMatch": {"from": "5530af38576214dd3553331c"}})
    .exec(function (err, docs){
        var set_difference = _.difference(["5530af38576214dd3553331c"], docs[0].messages.participants);
        console.log(set_difference); // => ["553f280040d50ef20f8c9d66"]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongo [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) and [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) use to check whether your criteria match check following query :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$messages" // first unwind messages array 
}, {
  "$match": {
    "messages.from": "5530af38576214dd3553331c" //match critreia 
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": "$messages.participants" // unwind participants array 
}, {
  "$match": {
    "messages.participants": {
      "$ne": "5530af38576214dd3553331c" // check messages.from not equals participants array  
    }
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "participants": "$messages.participants"
  }
}).pretty()
```